# Python Pandas merge and update dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am currently using Python and Pandas to form a stock price "database". I managed to find some codes to download the stock prices.

df1 is my existing database. Each time I download the share price, it will look like df2 and df3. Then, i need to combine df1, df2 and df3 data to look like df4.

Each stock has its own column.
Each date has its own row.

df1: Existing database

```
+----------+-------+----------+--------+
|   Date   | Apple | Facebook | Google |
+----------+-------+----------+--------+
| 1/1/2018 |   161 |       58 |   1000 |
| 2/1/2018 |   170 |       80 |        |
| 3/1/2018 |   190 |       84 |    100 |
+----------+-------+----------+--------+
```

df2: New data (2/1/2018 and 4/1/2018) and updated data (3/1/2018) for Google.

```
+----------+--------+
|   Date   | Google |
+----------+--------+
| 2/1/2018 |    500 |
| 3/1/2018 |    300 |
| 4/1/2018 |    200 |
+----------+--------+
```

df3: New data for Amazon

```
+----------+--------+
|   Date   | Amazon |
+----------+--------+
| 1/1/2018 |   1000 |
| 2/1/2018 |   1500 |
| 3/1/2018 |   2000 |
| 4/1/2018 |   3000 |
+----------+--------+
```

df4 Final output: Basically, it merges and updates all the data into the database. (df1 + df2 + df3) --> this will be the updated database of df1

```
+----------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
|   Date   | Apple | Facebook | Google | Amazon |
+----------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
| 1/1/2018 |   161 |       58 |   1000 |   1000 |
| 2/1/2018 |   170 |       80 |    500 |   1500 |
| 3/1/2018 |   190 |       84 |    300 |   2000 |
| 4/1/2018 |       |          |    200 |   3000 |
+----------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
```

I do not know how to combine `df1` and `df3`.

And I do not know how to combine `df1` and `df2` (add new row: 4/1/2018) while at the same time updating the data (2/1/2018 -> Original data: NaN; amended data: 500 | 3/1/2018 -> Original data: 100; amended data: 300) and leaving the existing intact data (1/1/2018).

Can anyone help me to get df4? =)

Thank you.

**EDIT: Based on Sociopath suggestion, I amended the code to:**

```
dataframes = [df2, df3]
df4 = df1

for i in dataframes:
    # Merge the dataframe
    df4 = df4.merge(i, how='outer', on='date')

    # Get the stock name
    stock_name = i.columns[1]

    # To check if there is any column with "_x", if have, then combine these columns
    if stock_name+"_x" in df4.columns:
        x = stock_name+"_x"
        y = stock_name+"_y"
        df4[stock_name] = df4[y].fillna(df4[x])
        df4.drop([x, y], 1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `merge`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2/1/2018','3/1/2018','4/1/2018'], 'Google':[500,300,200]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1/1/2018','2/1/2018','3/1/2018','4/1/2018'], 'Amazon':[1000,1500,2000,3000]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1/1/2018','2/1/2018','3/1/2018'], 'Apple':[161,171,181], 'Google':[1000,None,100], 'Facebook':[58,75,65]})
```

If the column is not present in current database simply use `merge` as below

```
df_new = df3.merge(df2, how='outer',on=['date'])
```

If the column in present in DB then use `fillna` to update the values as below:

```
df_new = df_new.merge(df1, how='outer', on='date')
#print(df_new)
df_new['Google'] = df_new['Google_y'].fillna(df_new['Google_x'])
df_new.drop(['Google_x','Google_y'], 1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    date       Apple    Facebook    Amazon  Google
0   1/1/2018    161.0   58.0        1000    1000.0
1   2/1/2018    171.0   75.0        1500    500.0
2   3/1/2018    181.0   65.0        2000    300.0
3   4/1/2018    NaN     NaN         3000    200.0
```

**EDIT**

More generic solution for later part.

```
dataframes = [df2, df3, df4]  

for i in dataframes:
    stock_name = list(i.columns.difference(['date']))[0]
    df_new = df_new.merge(i, how='outer', on='date')
    x = stock_name+"_x"
    y = stock_name+"_y"

    df_new[stock_name] = df_new[y].fillna(df_new[x])
    df_new.drop([x,y], 1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: ok cool. thanks =). I only got 1 more question. The example is Google. However, it might not be Google. Is there any way to avoid hardcoded 'Google_y' and 'Google_x' in the code?

Comment: yes there is!!! I'm assuming you will be having multiple dataframes. Get their column names(i.e. stock name) and use `for loop` over it and add postfix _x and _y. So you don't have to hardcopy column name.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!!! I have amended your suggested generic solution. See my edit. =)

Comment: @KaiWei might want to accept the answer too then :D

Comment: i think you may be able to do this with loc, in fewer lines.  something like: df1.loc(df2.index, df2.columns] = df2

not sure which would be more peformant/faster though